# Mongodb documents which dates contain non-zero timestamp

Tags: mongodb

Sorry for the title, I find it hard to explain in few words...

I have an `assets` collection with a `date` field. This field should only have the date part and the rest should be zeros, ie: `ISODate("2018-07-18T00:00:00.000Z")` however due to a bug I have some dates like: `ISODate("2017-12-16T08:35:20.201Z")`.

I would like to find those offending documents and fix their dates.

Is there any way to query something like

```
{
  date: {
    $miliseconds: {
      $not: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like `db.colname.find({$expr: {$ne:[ {$millisecond: "$date" },0]}});`

Comment: That seems to work, is there anyway to update those documents with a query instead of going one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cursor from the aggregate query and bulk updates to update the matching documents in 3.6 version.

Here is the shell sample.

```
var bulk = db.colname.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
var batch = 50; // Change batch size as you need

db.colname.aggregate([
     {$match : {$expr: {$ne:[ {$millisecond: "$date" },0]}}},
     {$project:{
       date:{$dateFromParts:{
         year:{$year:"$date"},
         month:{$month:"$date"},
         day:{$dayOfMonth:"$date"}
       }}
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    bulk.find( {"_id" : doc._id}).updateOne(
     { "$set": {"date" : doc.date}} 
   ); 
    count++;  
    if (count == batch) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.colname.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        count = 0;
    } 
});

if (count > 0) { 
   bulk.execute(); 
}
```